# find method does not have forEach property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose in Node.js with Typescript.

My schema is as follows:

```
Member = mongoose.model("Member", MemberSchema);
const MemberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  familyName: String,
  otherNames: String
}, { timestamps: true });
```

I am able to use the `find` method with an inline callback, but if I try the following:

```
Member.find({"_id": req.body.item._id})
  .forEach((result,i) => {
     result.isDeleted = true;
     mongoose.Collection.save(result);
  }
```

I get an error at `forEach`:

> Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'DocumentQuery'. Did you forget to use 'await'?

The mongoose documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#with-foreach-method) seems to say that there is a `forEach` method.

How can I use the `forEach` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the driver you're using, 
Here are some examples that help you:

### node-mongodb-native

```
Member.find({"_id": req.body.item._id}).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.isDeleted = true;
  mongoose.Collection.save(doc)
}, function(err) {
  // done or error
});
```

### mongoose

```
Member.find({"_id": req.body.item._id}).stream()
  .on('data', function(doc){
    doc.isDeleted = true;
    mongoose.Collection.save(doc)
  })
  .on('error', function(err){
    // handle error
  })
  .on('end', function(){
    // final callback
  });
```